# Initialize a property and access it from all methods of class

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is something that is probably really obvious, but I can't seem to get my head around how to get this to work - I am fairly new to OOP so please be gentle

I am creating a class that I can use to call  a few methods that will update data sources

Ideally I would like to instantiate the class and with a default property , then call methods that would look up this property  and perform actions based in its value, I would also like to be able to change this property after instantiation in order to reuse the same methods for different purposes.

The part is am struggling with is the setting of the property

I am setting my values as such

```
DataController.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface DataController : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *defaultValue;
-(void)radFunction;
-(NSArray)awesomeArray:(NSString *)urlString;
@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "DataController.h"
@implementation DataController
@synthesize defaultValue = _defaultValue;
+ (void)initialize {
//self.defaultValue causes error
NSString *defaultValue = @"somethingI want other methods to be able to access";
}

-(void)radFunction{
 NSLog(@" Default value %@", defaultValue);
}
@end
```

Any light you anyone can shed on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Firstly, this question is not related to Xcode by any means. You could use `emacs` for writing your code, and the question would still be the same.

Comment: Furthermore, you can't access instance variables and instance methods (and therefore properties) from within a class method. It just doesn't make sense. Ivars and instance methods are tied to/operate on a particular object, i. e. on an instance of a class. How would a class method know **which** object to operate on? And an ivar **in which object** to change its value?

Comment: I think the issue is that the asker doesn't understand how to initialize an instance of an NSObject subclass, and how to access @poperties on that instance. Just a thought...

Comment: @AlfieHanssen Exactly. So one thing you might want to include in your answer in bold italics all-caps (OK maybe not in all-caps) is that he needs to use an **instance method.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pick up a good iOS development basics book and read through it, it'd be super helpful for material like this.

.h

```
@interface DataController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * defaultValue;

- (id)initWithDefaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue;
- (void)radFunction;
- (NSArray)awesomeArray:(NSString *)urlString;

@end
```

#### .m

```
@implementation DataController

// No need to @synthesize anymore, this is now done for you by the compiler, 
// instance var of the @property will be accessible via _defaultValue

- (id)initWithDefaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         self.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)radFunction
{
    NSLog(@" Default value %@", self.defaultValue);
}
@end
```

#### Edit:

Note that instance variables & `@properties` cannot be accessed from within class methods. Class methods are declared with a `+` whereas instance methods are declared with a `-`. You're seeing an error in `+ (void)initialize;` because it's a class method and therefore `defaultValue` isn't available.

Comment: Thank you, I am currently making my way through Aaron Hillegass's Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide which has been great so far. However I came across this problem trying a few things out.

So thanks very much for the clarification

Comment: You got it, good luck, that's a great book